# Update sort order in MySQL along with insertion

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have `sort_order` in my mysql table `pages`, and I sort them by dragging in the list, and that order will save to the database, 1 being on top, and larger number follows in ASC order. Now when I insert a new entry, because the `sort_order` is empty by then, it comes at the top, I want it to come at the bottom.

I don't exactly remember but I think there was a more proper way to update the `sort_order` along with insertion into MySQL, but I can't do it now.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
// MYSQL INSERT into PAGES TABLE.
// And then
```

I want to run this query:

```
UPDATE pages set sort_order = max(sort_order)+1 where id = {id}
```

Please help me if something like this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
UPDATE pages
SET sort_order = (( SELECT selected_value
                    FROM (SELECT MAX(sort_order) AS selected_value
                           FROM pages) AS sub_selected_value) + 1
                  )
```